# How to report only differences in RIGHT SIDE text comparison with Beyond Compare?

Tags: scripting, comparison, beyondcompare, beyondcompare4

I am using Beyond Compare 4 to compare 2 text files. I run BCompare.exe in the Windows command line and run this script:

```
# Script.txt
select right.diff
text-report layout:side-by-side options:display-mismatches output-to:"%3" "%1" "%2"
```

My layout option is side-by-side, but I do not actually want this. I want the output report to show ONLY differences from the RIGHT SIDE.This is what I was attempting to do in the first line `select right.diff`, but from what I know, that command is used for folder comparisons, not text.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

**Note:**
The %1, %2, %3 refers to the file locations of the arguements I pass into the command line. %3 is my output file, %1 is left input file and %2 is right input file.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond Compare doesn't provide a method to output only one side in a report. A report layout that only outputs one side is on the feature wish list for a future version, but it doesn't have a scheduled release date.

Comment: Oh, okay. Have users discovered any workarounds to this? I can output an XML report so perhaps parsing that?

Comment: If you're automating it, output to XML, then parsing the XML is probably the best choice. Interactively, output to HTML, then open the HTML in Microsoft Excel and save as an Excel file for additional formatting.

Comment: My current manual process is to highlight the entire Right-side and pasting into Excel. Anyways, thanks Chris! I appreciate the quality work you guys are doing at Scooter Software!